# MYSQL - TRIGGER insert into another table values from a table when a tinyint is updated to TRUE

Tags: mysql, triggers, where-clause

I have 2 tables bid and job

```
CREATE TABLE test.bid_ (
ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
bid_name VARCHAR(45) NULL,
bid_won TINYINT(1) NULL,
job_ID INT NULL,
con_ID INT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (ID));
```

And,

```
CREATE TABLE test.job_ (
ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
job_name VARCHAR(45) NULL,
con_ID INT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (ID));
```

What I am trying to do is, insert bid.bid_name into job.job_name after bid_won is updated to TRUE. I just cannot wrap my head around the trigger or procedures needed. I am very new to triggers and procedures.

I would think a trigger like this would work:

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `test`.`bid_AFTER_UPDATE` AFTER UPDATE ON `bid` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO job (job_name,con_ID) 
SELECT bid_name,con_ID FROM bid WHERE OLD.bid_won <=> NEW.bid_won AND job_ID IS NULL
END
```

But I guess the AND clause is no good. Also, I would need to update the bid table with the new job_ID from job.ID that is created when the bid is made into a job. Any help would be appreciated.

** 
Does it always seem that when you find the answer to your question you hit your forehead and say "Of Course!!!", I think I have the answer to my problem @P.Salmon asked the question that really helped me with a more elegant solution.

> 'update the bid table with the new job_ID from job.ID that is created ' - is impossible,mysql will not allow you to action the table which fired the trigger. Why do you need the job table at all - it contains everything that bid has

I will just put in a column that would indicate whether it is a job or abid. However,the following trigger is producing the results I was looking for.

```
BEGIN

IF NEW.bid_won = TRUE
THEN 
INSERT INTO test.job (job_conID,job_name) SELECT 
bid_conID,bid_name,bid_desc,bidID FROM bid WHERE ID = NEW.ID;


ELSEIF NEW.bid_won = FALSE
THEN 
DELETE FROM job WHERE job_name = NEW.bid_name;

END IF;
END
```

I realize this may be a bit redundant, however, it demonstrates the fact that I hit my forehead on the 'NEW.' and 'OLD.' parts of the update. Basically, it is a switch.

Comment: 'update the bid table with the new job_ID from job.ID that is created ' - is impossible,mysql will not allow you to action the table which fired  the trigger. Why do you need the job table at all - it contains everything that bid has

Comment: I see your point. Maybe I should just create a column that would indicate whether it is a bid or job. I will consider that. Maybe I should not try to work on these things when I am to exhausted. :) . Really, by thinking of that it would resolve many issues. Thank you.I do think that I have the answer to my original question though, for future reference, and will post that for review.